# GCP External LoadBalancer jinja deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, jinja2, load-balancing, google-deployment-manager

I'm am trying to deploy an external Load Balancer using deployment manager with `.jinja` and `.yaml` files.

Currently I can only find documentation and resources on deploying internal Load Balancers, is deploying a external Load Balancer possible with `.jinja` and `.yaml`?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may deploy an external Load Balancer using .jinja or .yaml files. You may see this [link](https://github.com/sveronneau/gcp-dm/blob/master/LoadBalancer.yaml) on Github for reference on how to do this using YAML. You can create a .jinja file using the same API calls mentioned in that link and use it to create an external GCP LoadBalancer.  You can find sample deployment manager resource snippets in this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/google/resource-snippets) which can be used to create your deployment files.

Comment: Thanks for those links they seem very helpful, could you explain a little what is going on in the first link? Thanks!

Comment: There is no a single API to create a LoadBalancer(LB) as this is created using multiple GCE resources as explained in [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/apis), for which you can call all the APIs to create a LB.

Comment: The code is creating resources based on the resource type provided. You can see it is creating a backend service with health check with the  resource 'compute.v1.backendService'. The section '$(ref.apache-url-map.selfLink)' is creating a variable which calls a previous resource  backend service. Finally it is creating a forwarding rule to forward traffic to the internet on port 80. You can see this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2) for more information about the resource types used which will help you understand the code better.